# ubuntu - unable to set pm2 as service on boot

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-14.04, pm2

I'm launching an application and am able to use PM2 to run it however I'm looking at making sure PM2 launches on reboot of the server.

I have two users, root and a user for running the application. The user has sudo privileges.

Currently I am typing this command:

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup systemd -u USER --hp /home/USER
```

and the result:

```
[ERROR] Exit code : 1
[PM2][ERROR] systemctl start pm2-paul failed, see error above.
```

When I check jorunalctl for details, I see this:

```
pm2-user.service: PID file /home/user/.pm2/pm2.pid not readable (yet?) after 
start: No such file or directory
Failed to start PM2 process manager.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been struggling for a few hours now with this.

Comment: you should look in the official doc of PM2 http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/

Comment: @sheplu - I've followed the official documentation as described and encountered this error, so I am posting on here to try and seek some further help.

Comment: if you test the command with `sudo su` and not just `sudo` ?

Comment: I ended up just changing to the root user and setting the service up there. Thanks for the help regardless.